# JS в одном файле и условные конструкции

Tags: javascript, условия

Есть JS файл, который содержит в себе скрипты со всех страниц сайта (страниц довольно много).
Есть ли смысл прописывать внутри конструкции вроде подобной:

```
if (мы на странице N) {то выполнить этот код}
else if (мы на странице M) {то выполнить этот код}
```

Влияет ли это на скорость загрузки/обработки JS браузером: будет ли она быстрее или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Влияет ли это на скорость загрузки/обработки JS браузером: будет ли
>   она быстрее или нет?

Быстрее, чем что? С чем сравнивать?
На скорость загрузки влияет размер js-скрипта. Если он не гигантский и Вам удобно иметь один скрипт, то я бы посоветовал его не разбивать на отдельные скрипты. Браузеру как раз-таки удобнее загружать один скрипт, чем несколько.

На скорость обработки такая проверка не повлияет. Браузер выполняет скрипт только когда его просят и только ту часть, которую запрашивают.
Например при 'if (5 > 3 && 4 < 3 && ...)...' браузер не будет проверять на истину оставшуюся часть, тем более обрабатывать действие при истине.

Так что смело можно использовать приведённую Вами конструкцию. Но, возможно, будет удобнее использовать оператор [switch](http://javascript.ru/switch)

Comment: JS файлы объединяются в один при сборке. Соответственно файл содержит в себе скрипты со всего сайта. На странице A может вызываться функция N, а на странице B вызываться функция M. Вот мне и хотелось понять, будет ли разница в скорости, если я запихаю в условие код функций N и M(что мы находимся на нужной странице). Соответственно с этим и сравнивать.